# openstack python api script getting SSL error

Tags: python, openstack, python-novaclient

I have build new openstack based on `Queens` release and now trying to learn python SDK api script and stuck here not sure what is wrong.

my script

```
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v3
from keystoneclient import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
auth_url = 'http://172.28.0.9:5000/v3'
username = 'dev'
user_domain_name = 'Default'
project_name = 'dev'
project_domain_name = 'Default'
password = 'Password123'
auth = v3.Password(auth_url=auth_url,
                   username=username,
                   password=password,
                   project_id='344506541fd94f068d25990af3eff4b8',
                   user_domain_name=user_domain_name)
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)
#keystone.projects.list()

from novaclient import client
nova = client.Client(2, session=keystone.session)
nova.flavors.list()
```

Getting error

```
[dev@openstack ~]$ python /tmp/myscript.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py:200: UserWarning: Using keystoneclient sessions has been deprecated. Please update your software to use keystoneauth1.
  warnings.warn('Using keystoneclient sessions has been deprecated. '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/o.py", line 22, in <module>
    nova.flavors.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/flavors.py", line 145, in list
    return self._list("/flavors%s" % detail, "flavors", filters=qparams)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 257, in _list
    resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 328, in get
    return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 77, in request
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 487, in request
    resp = super(LegacyJsonAdapter, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 213, in request
    return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/session.py", line 428, in request
    resp = send(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/session.py", line 466, in _send_request
    raise exceptions.SSLError(msg)
keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.SSLError: SSL exception connecting to https://10.30.2.9:8774/v2.1/flavors/detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.30.2.9', port=8774): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.1/flavors/detail (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),))
```

`10.30.2.9` is my F5 load-balancer and i did configured `8774` correctly route to nova api server.

my horizon GUI working fine and also all `openstack` commands working fine without error.

Answer (score 1):

`verify=False` helps:

```py
keystone = client.Client(session=sess, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the certificate for SSL.

```
sess = session.Session(auth=auth, verify=path_to_certificate)
        keystone = keystoneclient.Client(session=sess)
```

Perhaps there is an option to disable SSL.